# what's mean 'the use of this feature is restricted'?

Tags: resources, pool, masking

I used the Xenserver 6.1 in my two servers.

I want to use live-migration.

But, they can't to join same resource pool .

So, I use cpu-masking feature.

However, it isn't working, too.

My first server info is..

[server-1]

```
cpu_count                : 32
                     vendor: GenuineIntel
                      speed: 2000.066
            modelname: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 v2 @ 2.00GHz
               family: 6
                model: 62
             stepping: 4
                flags: fpu de tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr mca cmov pat 
                       clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht nx constant_tsc 
                       nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq vmx est ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2
                       x2apic popcnt aes hypervisor ida arat tpr_shadow vnmi
                       flexpriority ept vpid
             features: 77bee3ff-bfebfbff-00000001-2c100800
features_after_reboot: 77bee3ff-bfebfbff-00000001-2c100800
    physical_features: 77bee3ff-bfebfbff-00000001-2c100800
             maskable: no
```

My second server info is..

[server-2]

```
cpu_count                : 24
               vendor: GenuineIntel
                speed: 2000.040
            modelname: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz
               family: 6
                model: 45
             stepping: 7
                flags: fpu de tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr mca cmov pat clflush
                       acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht nx constant_tsc nonstop_tsc 
                       aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq vmx est ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic 
                       popcnt aes hypervisor ida arat tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority 
                       ept vpid
             features: 17bee3ff-bfebfbff-00000001-2c100800
features_after_reboot: 17bee3ff-bfebfbff-00000001-2c100800
    physical_features: 17bee3ff-bfebfbff-00000001-2c100800
             maskable: full
```

I use this command in my server1.

```
xe host-set-cpu-features features=17bee3ff-bfebfbff-00000001-2c100800 uuid=6c91e5c8-06b9-4b5c-a41d-ec4d6b2c44aa
```

Result is 'The use of this feature is restricted'.

And, I use this command in my server2.

```
xe host-set-cpu-features features=77bee3ff-bfebfbff-00000001-2c100800 uuid=53566e64-a24f-42a4-8a6d-a26e9f740fa8
```

Result is same.

What's mean this message?

'The use of this feature is restricted'.

How to use cpu-masking in my environment?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message when trying to join a host with a cpu model E5503 to a pool with two hosts with E5645's. I was not able to get past this error with XenServer 6.1, but after upgrading the pool and the lone host to 6.2 I was able to apply a mask and join the third host to the pool without further issue.